# simple PHP script with sleep function not working, Browser prompt to download .php file

Tags: php, performance, timeout

When I execute following php file (after some time) browser will ask to download file

```
<?php
    ini_set("max_execution_time", 0);
    set_time_limit(0);
    for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
       echo time();
       echo "<Br>";
       $sec=rand(15,30);
       sleep($sec);
    }
?>
```

in browser nothing `echo` prompt for download PHP file (if file take approximate 2 or more minute to execute than this problem occurred)

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove that ini set..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server decides to throw you the php source code instead of running it, your server setup is messed up.

Not sure how it got messed up because your screenshot hints that you are using XAMPP. In this case, try reinstalling XAMPP.

Comment: but not getting what is the problem.

Comment: @RSSisodiya The problem is that Apache is not recognizing PHP as a script, and feeds it to you as a regular file.